# Bootstrap: How do I identify the Bootstrap version?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to update Bootstrap on a site, but I don't know the installed version.

How can I identify the bootstrap version, with only bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.js files?

There is no version in the CSS file and the min.js file contains the following comment.

```
/*!
* Bootstrap.js by @fat & @mdo
* Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc.
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
*/
```

Answer (score 226, accepted):

In the top of the `bootstrap.css` you should have comments like the below:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.3.1
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat.
 */
```

If they are not there, then they have probably been deleted.

**VERSIONS:**

You can review version history [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases). Backward compatibility shouldn't be broken if the source is v2.0.0 (Jan 2012) and above. If it is prior to v2.0.0 there are details on upgrading [here](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/).

Comment: Tanner, i'm worry about backward compatibility for js

Comment: i realise that bootstrap 3 didn't come out until aug 2013 (after this question and answer), but for anyone reading after this date - note that bootstrap v3.x is not backwards compatible with v2.x http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: The comment "can you not just upgrade to the latest version?" stops me giving this an upvote. It's unnecessary and doesn't help answer the question. And besides, if only upgrading to the latest version was that easy.

Comment: If someone have updated the bootstrap.css file and removed the version details from the top at that time, you won't be able to find version like this method.

Answer (score 98):

You can also check the bootstrap version via the javascript console in the browser:

Looks like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66194641/1608226) works better with Bootstrap 4/5:

```js
bootstrap.Tooltip.VERSION // => '5.2.0'
```

Where [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233731/1608226) works best for Bootstrap 3. It can also work for Bootstrap 4, but may not work for Bootstrap 5.

```js
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION // => "3.3.7"
```

Note that for older versions of Bootstrap (less than 3 or so), you'll probably need to search the page's JavaScript or CSS files for the bootstrap version. Just came across this on an app using Bootstrap 2.3.2. In this case, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15335621) is likely the correct one, and you'll need to search the source code for the Bootstrap source file itself to find what version is being used.

Comment: `jQuery.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION`

for no conflict cases :) Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it is the easiest to access.

Answer (score 34):

**Method 1 - Very Simple**

In `Package.json` - you'll see bootstrap package installed with version mentioned.

```
"dependencies": {
    // ...
   "bootstrap": "x.x.x"
    // ...
}
```

**Method 2**

1. Open `node_modules` folder and under that
2. Search and open `bootstrap` folder
3. Now you'll be able to see version number in the following files

   - `package.json`
   - `scss/bootstrap.scss` or `css/bootstrap.css`
   - `README.md`

Comment: The first method you propose, checking `package.json`, only shows you the _minimum_ version required to satisfy the build. It does not show which version you have installed. Have a look at the description of [Tilde & Caret Shorthand](https://nodesource.com/blog/semver-a-primer/#tildecaretshorthand)

Comment: @Tony brother package.json file contains installed packages along with their version numbers.

Comment: The version number of each dependency is _not necessarily_ the version installed on your computer. [NPM docs state](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file) "When you run npm install, npm will download dependencies and devDependencies that are listed in package.json *that meet the semantic version requirements* listed for each." (my emphasis). The tilde and caret characters allow you to define a _range of acceptable versions_, so they will not always match what is installed.

Answer (score 9):

An easy way to do this, without searching files or folders would be:

- Open your web page on browser
- press ctrl+U
- search bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.min.css, then click it (it would open source file)
- at first line (commented) you should see the Bootstrap version

Answer (score 5):

The Bootstrap version will be stated at the top of the CSS file. Simply open it and look at the top of the file.

e.g.

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.3.0
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat.
 */
```

Comment: Which CSS file?

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, and there have been several changes to Bootstrap over the years. One of the most common issues I encounter when I don't know what version of Bootstrap I'm using is that the header comment / docblock is missing from the file.

This answer was written after the release of 5.1.3 and 4.6.1. If you update it, please update those version numbers as well!

Here are the ways I have discovered (thanks to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/versions/ and https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases) to figure out what version you're using using feature-sniffing. Note that this list only covers the CSS portion!

## v5

v5.1 - added the `.placeholder` and `.placeholder-glow` classes
v5.0 - removed `.media` and added the `xxl` breakpoint (`.col-xxl-12`)

## v4

v4.6 - Added `.navbar-nav-scroll` class
v4.5 - Added `.user-select-none`, `.user-select-auto`, and `.user-select-none` classes
v4.4 - Added `.row-cols-*` classes
v4.3 - Added `.stretched-link` and `.text-break` classes
v4.2 - Added `.font-weight-lighter` and `.font-weight-bolder` classes
v4.1 - Added `.table-borderless` and `.text-monospace` classes
v4.0 - Removed `.img-responsive`. Added `.img-fluid`

## v3

v3.4 - Added `.row-no-gutters` class
v3.3 - Added `.media-left` and `.media-right` classes
v3.2 - Added `.sr-only-focusable` class
v3.1 - Added `.text-justify`, `.modal-sm` and `.modal-lg` classes
v3.0 - Removed `.span#` classes. Added `.col-X-#` classes

- # is a number from 1 to 12
- X is one of `xs`, `sm`, `md`, or `lg`

## v2

v2.3 - Added `.text-left`, `.text-center`, and `.text-right` classes
v2.2 - Added `.media` class
v2.1 - Added `.uneditable-input` and `.uneditable-textarea` classes
v2.0 - Added `.table` and `.table-*` classes

## v1

v1.4 - Added `.condensed-table` class
v1.3 - Added `.thumbnail` class
v1.2 - Added `.one-third` `.two-thirds` classes

Anything before this was not tracked reliable, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

if you have Node.js and npm installed
then you can use this to know the version in powershell/terminal:

```
npm view bootstrap
```

Answer (score 2):

Shoud be stated on the top of the page.

Something like.

```
/* =========================================================
 * bootstrap-modal.js v1.4.0
 * http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal
 * =========================================================
 * Copyright 2011 Twitter, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * ========================================================= */
```

Comment: "the page" - which page?

Comment: @Matt should be boostrap.min.js or boostrap.min.css or boostrap.scss for example. You can search for those files even in the Developer Tools when you inspect your web app in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to locate the bootstrap file (bootstrap.css OR bootstrap.min.css) and read through the docblock, you'll see something like this

`Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com)`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the version and little information that helps you to know that you imported successfully, do the following:

1. open your browser.
2. Ctrl+Shift+l or F12
3. Keep search for Sources then under top, you will find your URL like
   http://localhost:4200, then under it you will find styles.css.

Answer (score 0):

That comment looks like it is a custom version of Bootstrap v2.3.3, here is the default header in the .css, notice the last comment line:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.3.2
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world by @mdo and @fat.
 */
```

What are you trying to accomplish?  If it's customization then you have a set of files to work with though that seems like a bad idea.  Otherwise, I would suggest going with the full build of v4.1.x since that is the current release.

Answer (score 0):

Open package.json and look under dependencies. You should see:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "bootstrap-less": "^3.8.8"
    ...
    }
```

for angular 5 and over

Answer (score 0):

To expound more on [@vrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57611970/10907864)

To view the bootstrap version of a website in your web browser, do the following:

**First Method**:

- Open the website on your favourite browser
- Press **Ctrl** + **U** to view the web page source
- Look at the head section for a file named `boostrap.min.js` or `boostrap.min.css`. It should look like this `<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
- Then click it to open the source file
- This will display the bootstrap version of the website. It should look like this: `Bootstrap v4.4.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)`

**Second Method**:

- Open the website on your favourite browser
- Press **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **I** to inspect the webpage element
- In the inspect console, click on the **Style Editor** tab
- And then click on `boostrap.min.css`
- This will display the bootstrap version of the website.  It should look like this: `Bootstrap v4.4.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)`

[image: Bootstrap version in console]

That's all

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

you will see your current bootstrap version in this "bootstrap.min.css/bootstrap.css" files, In the top section

Answer (score 0):

You can locate it in the doc Block from `bootstrap.min.css`, at the top part.

Answer (score -3):

To check what version you currently have, you can use -v for the command line/console terminal.

**bootstrap -v**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-cli

Comment: I'm glad you asked :) @bhansa There are various ways to get there. One could: 

- Use the command prompt to get the the project folder file and type the command. 
- Go the file explorer and open up Git Bash/Git Shell/etc... and type the command. 
- Open up the terminal within your IDE (Visual Code/Webstorm/Atom, etc) and type the command there.

Comment: This only displays bootstrap-cli version.