# How to know bootstrap version in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `bootstrap-sass (3.3.1.0)` in my Rails project.

How can I know the twitter bootstrap itself's version?

I found this question, but there were no answer for Rails environment.

[How to identify bootstrap version? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335537/how-to-identify-bootstrap-version)

#### following @Avdept's answer

```
$ bundle exec gem which bootstrap-sass
/Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.1.0/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb
$ cd /Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.1.0/
$ find . -name "*.css"
$ find . -name "_bootstrap.scss"
./assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss
```

So I couldn't find `bootstrap.css` in which there is version number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases inside gems are same css as in original version. 
You can find path of where your gem installed using

```
gem which bootstrap-sass
```

Then just go to this folder, find css file and check top of css file

Comment: I couldn't find the `bootstrap.css` file in the gem, but your first advice is quite enough for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to docs:

Version

bootstrap-sass version reflects the upstream version, with an additional number for Sass-specific changes.
So if you have installed gem not long time ago, most likely you will have up to date version of BS

Comment: what is BS in version of BS?