# How can I get Bootstrap version via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to get the Bootstrap version via calling a function? I did some research but couldn't find any way. The version information is included in the comments at the beginning like this:

`/*!

- Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
- Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
- Licensed under the MIT license
  */`

But in case the comments are removed how do I get the bootstrap version? Bootstrap plugins have a version defined in them but I'm looking for the general Bootstrap version, not version of a particular plugin.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The version of each of Bootstrap's jQuery plugins can be accessed via the VERSION property of the plugin's constructor. For example, for the tooltip plugin:

```js
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION // => "3.3.7"
```

[src //getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-version-nums](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-version-nums)

if you mean from the css, then yu ahve to AJAX the file and `.match(/v[.\d]+[.\d]/);`

Comment: I have seen this in 3.3.7 version but looks like it's gonna change in the future, v4.0.0-alpha.6 version doesn't have version property.

Comment: Actually it have, but defined little bit differently https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/dist/alert.js#L150

Comment: @Andrey yeah tested it now, `$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION` works for new version as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution no longer works with Bootstrap 5 if you aren't using jQuery.   See my comment below for a more general solution.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this code found [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16264) :

```
  var getBootstrapVersion = function () {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  var script = $('script[src*="bootstrap"]');
  if (script.length == 0) {
    return deferred.reject();
  }

  var src = script.attr('src');
  $.get(src).done(function(response) {
    var matches = response.match(/(?!v)([.\d]+[.\d])/);
    if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
      version = matches[0];
      deferred.resolve(version);
    }
  });

  return deferred;
};

getBootstrapVersion().done(function(version) {
  console.log(version); // '3.3.4'
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Checked on the jQuery-less Bootstrap5, to get the version you just neeed

```
let version = bootstrap.Tooltip.VERSION
```

Comment: I just want to note that this solution works for both Bootstrap 4 and 5 and should be considered the currently CORRECT ANSWER.  The selected answer only works with Bootstrap 3 and 4.  None of the solutions work for Bootstrap < 3, with CSS only Bootstrap, or with alternative implementations like Bootstrap Vue.   +1

Answer (score 7):

This spinoff of the Constructor method adds a fallback plugin and returns an array:

```
var version = ($().modal||$().tab).Constructor.VERSION.split('.');
```

You can access the major revision with `version[0]`, of course.

Comment: this is actually the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

you can find bootstrap version here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#version-numbers

```
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION // => "4.3.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that works for all the currently supported versions of Bootstrap (3.x, 4.x, 5.x), this should work:

```
var version = typeof bootstrap === 'undefined' ?
   $().tooltip.Constructor.VERSION : bootstrap.Tooltip.VERSION;
```